# C# Duplicate DOCX File Using OpenXML

Tags: c#, .net, clone, openxml

I'm trying to duplicate the docx file contents and save them within the same file using OpenXML in C#

Here is the code:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(wordFileNamePath, true))
{
    foreach(OpenXmlElement element in wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.ChildElements)
    {
        OpenXmlElement cloneElement = (OpenXmlElement)element.Clone();
        wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Append(cloneElement);
    }
    wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
}
```

The code is working fine and does what I need. My problem is that the resulting docx file is partially corrupted. When I open my file I get the following two messages:
[image]

Clicking on 'OK' then 'Yes' will open the file normally. However, the file keeps being corrupted until I 'save as' it (with the same or with a different name). That's how the new saved file becomes fixed.

By using the Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool for Microsoft Office, I can Validate the file and see the reflected code. Validating the file will give the following 5 errors:

[image]

So I think that "Clone" function that I use in my code copies the element as it is so when it is appended to the document, some IDs duplications occur.

Any idea to get a proper working DOCX file after duplicating itself? Any alternative code is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your method is that it creates invalid Open XML markup. Here is why.

Let's say you have a very simple Word document that is represented by the following markup:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
  <w:body>
    <w:p>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>First paragraph</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>Second paragraph</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
  <w:body>
<w:document>
```

In your `foreach` loop, `wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.ChildElements` will be a single-element list that only contains the `w:body` element. Thus, you create a deep clone of the `w:body` element and append that to the `w:document`. The resulting Open XML markup looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
  <w:body>
    <w:p>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>First paragraph</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>Second paragraph</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
  <w:body>
  <w:body>
    <w:p>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>First paragraph</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>Second paragraph</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
  <w:body>
<w:document>
```

The above is a `w:document` with two `w:body` child elements, which is invalid Open XML markup as `w:document` must have exactly one `w:body` child element. Thus, Word shows that error message.

To fix this, you need to work with `Document.Body` wherever you just use `Document`. The following, streamlined example shows how to do it.

```cs
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(wordFileNamePath, true))
{
    Body body = wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
    IEnumerable<OpenXmlElement> clonedElements = body
        .Elements()
        .Select(e => e.CloneNode(true))
        .ToList();

    body.Append(clonedElements);
}
```

You'll see that I did not save the `Document` explicitly as that is not necessary due to the `using` statement and the fact that those documents are auto-saved by default. Secondly, I used `ToList()` to materialize the collection before appending. This is to avoid any issues while enumerating elements that are changed at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

Why wouldn't be corrupted? You are opening a document, getting all of the child elements, and writing them to the same document. I am not sure what is that supposed to do.

Comment: Yes, suppose you have an image, text, and whatever element. I'm expecting them to be repeated (appended) to the document.

Comment: @yazanpro, then you should only take elements from the body. Something like: `wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.ChildElements`. And append them to the body `wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Append(cloneElement);`

Comment: You mean:
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(wordFileNamePath, true))
{
    foreach(OpenXmlElement element in wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.ChildElements)
    {
        OpenXmlElement cloneElement = (OpenXmlElement)element.Clone();
        wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Append(cloneElement);
    }
    wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
}

I got the same problem

Comment: I mean The same exact resulting file that has duplicate IDs in elements

Comment: @Yazanpro, somewhat offtopic, but why do you want to do this?